# Error in testing

Tags: java

I am having problems with my test. It looks like it's simple. All you have to do is delete a space, but I keep getting an error for some reason.

```
@Override
    public String format(String template) {
        if(template.equals("%t")){
          return String.format("%02 seconds", getSeconds());
        }
        else if(template.equals("%h:%M:%S")) {
            return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", getHours(), getMinutes(), getSeconds());
        }
        else if(template.equals("%d days, %h hours, %m minutes, and %s seconds")){
            return String.format("%d days,%2d hours,%2d minutes, and %2d seconds", getDays(), getHours(),
                    getMinutes(), getSeconds());
        }
        else return null;

    }


 @Test
    public void testFormatExample1() {
        assertEquals("3 days, 4 hours, 0 minutes, and 9 seconds",
                fromDHMS(3, 4, 0, 9)
                        .format("%d days, %h hours, %m minutes, and %s seconds"));
    }
```

This is what I should get

```
3 days, 4 hours, 0 minutes, and 9 seconds
```

yet this is what I keep getting

```
Expected :3 days, 4 hours, 0 minutes, and 9 seconds
Actual   :3 days, 4 hours, 0 minutes, and  9 seconds
```

I've tried everything to get rid of that extra space in `and  9 seconds`

If I go to the last case of my if statement, and I delete the space between `and` and `%2d seconds`, It still doesn't work.   I did it for the spaces before it and it worked.

Does anyone know the problem?

Comment: Where's the code for `fromDHMS()`?

Comment: Didn't think it was necessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is just `%2d` - you've *explicitly* asked for the number of seconds to be converted into a minimum of two characters. Just make it `%d` and it should be fine. See the [`Formatter` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for details.

Note that at the moment, if you have 10 or more hours and 10 or more minutes, you probably won't get the output you expect - you'll have no space after the comma. I suspect you want a format string of:

```
"%d days, %d hours, %d minutes, and %d seconds"
```

As an aside, however, I don't think that only accepting some very specific input templates is a very good idea - if that's all you need to support, I'd use an enum to represent them instead.